# Instanciar Herencia, no aparece las funciones especificas

Tags: java

Uso herencia pero no puedo usar sus metodos propios de la clase

Esta es la clase general

```
public  class Animal {
    public void caminar(int x){
        System.out.println("Caminando Animal "+x);
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase especifica

```
public class Perro extends Animal{

    public Perro(){
    super();
    }
    public void ladrar(int x){
        System.out.println("Ladrando");
    }
}
```

y cuando intento usar la funcion ladrar() no puedo, como puedo usarlo?

```
Animal animal=new Perro();
animal.ladrar()// no puedo usar esta funcion
```

o si o si debo instanciar asi: `Perro animal=new Perro();`

Comment: Si lo instancias como Animal solo vas a tener disponible los metodos de Animal. Si quieres usar las del hijo tendras que castear. PD: No son funciones si no metodos.

Comment: @JDev como se castea asi: animal=(Gato) animal; sale error

Comment: @JDev hago el casting animal=(Perro)animal; pero sigo sin poder usar los metodos propios

Comment: Lo estas haciendo mal. Sería `Perro perro = (Perro) animal;`

Comment: @JDev se puede hacer esto?:    Perro perro=(Perro)animal;
        perro.ladrar(0);
        
        Gato gato=(Gato)animal;
        gato.maullar(0);

Comment: Si siempre y cuando el objeto a castear sea creado con el constructor del hijo.

Comment: @JDev crea tu respuesta porfavor

Answer (score 0):

Para poder usar los métodos del hijo tienes que castearlo a su clase Hija.

```
Animal animal=new Perro();
Perro perro = (Perro) animal
perro.ladrar(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

La manera en la que estas aplicando la herencia es errónea.

```
Animal animal=new Perro();
animal.ladrar()// no puedo usar esta funcion
```

Efectivamente en lo anterior tienes que castear los tipos si quieres que funcione de esa manera. Aun así sería mucho mas lógico si instancias el siguiente objeto de esta manera:

```
Perro perro=new Perro();
perro.ladrar()//
```

De esta forma accedes a los métodos del hijo y del padre. Pudiendo ejecutar, por ejemplo la siguiente sentencia también:

```
perro.caminar(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una muy buena oprtunidad para usar la pseudo-mónada `Optional` de [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), que te permitiré poner tu código en un estilo funcional.

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Optionalinstanceof {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Perro();

        Optional<Perro> opcionalmenteUnPerro = animal instanceof Perro
                ? Optional.ofNullable((Perro) animal)
                : Optional.empty();

        opcionalmenteUnPerro.ifPresent((perro) -> perro.ladrar(1));

        animal.caminar(5);
    }
}
```

Como podrás ver, la clase `Optional` solamente acepta o un valor o una bandera que indica que está vacío.

la palabra reservada `instanceof` nos permite saber si se trata o no de una instancia de una clase en particular, en nuestro caso preguntamos si la el animal es un perro, y si es que sí, guardamos el animal con tipo Perro, si no, no guardamos nada.

Posteriormente checamos, si guardamos un perro le pedimos que ladre mediante un bonito lambda.

Si observas nunca definimos una variable `perro`, pero en el lambda la trata como si existiera, eso es porque los lmabdas son una notación corta para evitar escribir código que se puede omitir, si no te acostumbras a los lambdas puedes usarlo en su forma tradicional como:

```
    opcionalmenteUnPerro.ifPresent(new Consumer<Perro>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Perro perro) {
            perro.ladrar(1);
        }
    });
```

La salida de este programa es

> Ladrando
>
> Caminando Animal 5

Si animal no fuera de tipo Perro solamente imprimirá

> Caminando Animal 5

Ahora si no te acostumbras al estilo funcional, a la antiguita el mismo codigo se haría así:

```
public class Optionalinstanceof {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Perro();

        Perro unPerro = animal instanceof Perro
                ? (Perro) animal // casting
                : null;

        if (unPerro != null) { // prevenimos NPE
            unPerro.ladrar(1);
        }

        animal.caminar(5);
    }
}
```